# Unable to delete item via ribbon Delete Item button

Tags: ribbon, delete

I have a generic list of items in SharePoint 2010.

When I select an item with the left column checkbox, then select Delete Item from the ribbon, the item does not delete. Looking at the traffic in Fiddler, I am receiving an Access Denied response. I am a SC admin, and have full control to the list and recycle bin.

When I select the exact same item, and use the context menu (ECB) Delete Item choice, the item is deleted. When I check the recycle bin, the item is present, so it did delete successfully. Fiddler traffic looks normal.

What can explain this behavior? How can I correct it so that the ribbon Delete Item button works?

By the way, this a claims-based auth environment, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a tip [here](http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/access-denied-when-trying-to-access-a-wcf-service-in-sharepoint-2010/) from Donal Conlon, I discovered that the IIS web site did not have Anonymous access enabled. I enabled Anonymous for the virtual root site, and now the ribbon delete is working.

I am working through the other security implications of making this change, but it appears that claims is still authenticating correctly and I have proper access to the site. The only difference I can see so far is that I can now browse to the web service endpoints (before I was getting Access Denied there).

Answer (score 0):

May have partially answered my own question. I believe the access denied is to the request for this URL:

https://testsites.com/sites/testsite/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery

I'm now investigating permissions to this service.